Proving $X_t = \exp(aB_t-\frac{a^2}{2}t)$ is a Bounded Martingale
If we consider the martingale
$$X_t = \exp(aB_t-\frac{a^2}{2}t)$$
with $a>0$ and $B_t$ is brownian motion. The process $X_{\tau \wedge t}$ is a bounded martingale. $u$ is real number for which $B_t$ can hit, $\tau$ is the first hitting time of $u$. The probability of $B_t$ hitting $u$ is $1$ as the probability of the brownian motion hitting any point is $1$.
Im not really sure how to go about this as $B_t$ can go to infinity and cant see any justification for the second term bringing it down faster than the potential to go straight to infinity.
Also why isnt the stopped Brownian motion bounded?

What does bounded mean here ?

Also: what is $\tau,?$ I can define a $\tau$ for you that makes this as bounded as you want.

edited now, defined the $\tau$

@Wei edited now

$X_{\tau\wedge t}$ is bounded if and only if $u \geq 0$. If $u < 0$ then $X$ can become arbitrarily large before the stopping time. Or by "bounded" do you really mean $L^1$-bounded or $L^2$-bounded or something else?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem. Bounded was all my book said. It must be bounded in the sense of one of these 3 conditions in the wiki link

@Wei edited now

Too long for a comment, or answer, since you still have trouble understanding why $X_{\tau\wedge t}$ is bounded.
(For those who need evidence.)
When we choose $u>B_0=0$ and define $\tau=\inf\{t\ge 0:B_t=u\}$ we can be sure
that, at any time $t$ before $\tau(\omega)$ the path $B_t(\omega)$ is below $u\,.$
Formally (you should try to free yourself of such formalism):
$$\tag1
B_{\rho(\omega)}(\omega)\le u\,,\quad\text{ whenever }\quad\rho(\omega)\le\tau(\omega)\,.
$$
Hence,
$$\tag2
B_{\tau(\omega)\wedge t}(\omega)\le u\,.
$$
It follows that
$$\tag3
0\le X_{\tau(\omega)\wedge t}=\exp\left(aB_{\tau(\omega)\wedge t}-\tfrac{a^2t}2\right)\le e^{aB_{\tau(\omega)\wedge t}}\le e^{au}\,.
$$
Since this holds for all $\omega$ we have shown that $X_{\tau(\omega)\wedge t}$ is bounded.
